# Existe alguna regla de precedencia en español para el uso de complementos circunstanciales?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

Estaba leyendo un meme en Facebook que decía:

> «Jabón corporal en barra para niños con forma de hipopótamo»

y el meme se reía de que el producto no llevaba coma. Pero en realidad el enunciado sería más entendible si se alterara el orden.

> «Jabón corporal en barra con forma de hipopótamo para niños».

Pero nunca leí acerca de que los complementos circunstanciales tengan alguna regla de precedencia. Por lo tanto la pregunta que quería hacer es:

¿Existe alguna regla de precedencia en español para el uso de complementos circunstanciales?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Jabón corporal en barra para niños con forma de hipopótamo" es una frase nominal. Lo que acarrea ambigüedad es el orden de los modificadores (M) del núcleo (N) de la frase, que es "jabón". Si tenemos una secuencia:

N + M1 + M2 + M3

y M1 o M2 contienen un sustantivo que pueda interpretarse como calificado por el modificador que sigue, es inevitable que haya ambigüedad. La mejor solución consistirá en alterar el orden de los modificadores hasta que la ambigüedad se aclare:

- Jabón corporal en barra con forma de hipopótamo para niños

Si no hay ambigüedad, el idioma español ofrece bastante flexibilidad en cuanto al orden de los modificadores, pero en general estarán más cerca del núcleo aquellos que designen una cualidad más intrínseca u objetiva del sustantivo en cuestión, por ejemplo:

- ser humano increíble (NO ser increíble humano)
- máquina lavadora de última generación (NO máquina de última generación lavadora)

Los complementos circunstanciales y predicativos o atributivos aparecen en el predicado, e indican el modo, lugar, tiempo, etc. en que se constata un estado u ocurre una acción. El idioma español es bastante flexible y, nuevamente, se buscará evitar la ambigüedad y procurar que la frase verbal fluya mejor. Ver los distintos significados de estas oraciones según la ubicación de "triste":

- Camina triste por la calle durante la noche / Camina por la calle triste durante la noche / Camina por la calle durante la noche triste

Las comas pueden evitar la ambigüedad y definir el significado:

- Jabón corporal en barra para niños, con forma de hipopótamo
- Camina por la calle, triste, durante la noche.
- Camina por la calle durante la noche, triste.